# Suffixes for Strings

Tags: java, string

How would I add something to the end of a string, like an integer?

Example:

```
int i = 0;
String string = Integer.toString(i);
string = string + suffix;
```

I tried using the plus sign to add the suffix but it didn't work. Any help?

Comment: What is the value of `suffix`? What was the output when the code was executed? What did you expect? Please help us to help you.

Comment: What you've written will work just fine! The problem must be something else - if you want to get the problem solved you'll need to post an SSCCE or at least give some detail about how you're using the resulting String.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you've given will work absolutely fine:

```
String suffix = "suffix";
int i = 0;
String string = Integer.toString(i);
string = string + suffix;
System.out.println(string); // 0suffix
```

My guess is that in your *real* code, you aren't assigning the result back to the variable. Note that the `+` operator doesn't modify the *existing* string - it creates a *new* string. So:

```
String text = "text";
String copy = text;
text = text + "suffix";
System.out.println(copy); // Still just "text"; refers to original string
```

Comment: What if it's be written like string + " suffix" ? Does that work?

Comment: @rulla101: Yes, that would work fine. A string literal is still a string reference...

Answer (score 1):

You may use [concat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#concat%28java.lang.String%29) member function of string class.

```
string = string.concat( Integer.toString(i) );
```

Comment: No you don't. Using `+` will work perfectly well, and is usually more readable.

Comment: @JonSkeet - What a pleasant surprise ? After being on SO for more than 10 months, got a comment from you :) I changed the context to - "You may use ... "

Answer (score 1):

The most idiomatic way to do this in modern Java is `String.format("%s%d", s, i);` where `s` is a `String` and `i` is an `int`.

Comment: It partly depends on whether you want locale-sensitive output. This will use a locale-sensitive formatter; `text + integer` won't.

Answer (score 0):

The + operator, if the first parameter is a string will automatically convert the other parameters to strings.

E.g. in the following code: -

```
String myString = "fred";
int suffix = 0;
myString = myString + suffix;
```

myString will be "fred0";